# looping thru array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

hey guys so I'm trying to solve this problem here

> Make a function that looks through a list (first argument) and returns
>   an array of all objects that have equivalent property values (second
>   argument).

but i can't seem to loop thru an array of objects if my life depended on it..... Here is my following code

```
function where(collection, source) {
  for(var prop in collection){
    if(collection.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      console.log("collection." + prop + "=" + collection[prop]);
    }
  }
}

where([{ first: 'Romeo', last: 'Montague' }, { first: 'Mercutio', last: null }, { first: 'Tybalt', last: 'Capulet' }], { last: 'Capulet' });
```

i was reading documents on hasOwnProperty method and for in loops but it seems like I am utilizing them wrong, any guidance is appreciated, thanks.

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE**

Comment: Dont you need to use 'source' somewhere in your code?

Comment: @WandMaker im not following you....

Comment: Second parameter of 'where' method, how are you using it?

Comment: @WandMaker i havent gotten that far yet, I'm still struggling on how to iterate over an array of objects and print their keys and properties.....once i do that, thats a whole other ball park...

Comment: This question has been answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript

Comment: @WandMaker i know how to loop thru arrays, i don't know how to loop thru an array of objects until now, thanks to the answer below. this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Not sure there is much difference though.  Glad that you got solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `for...in` loop is not what you want for iterating over arrays in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Use the sequential for loop to loop through the array, and the `for..in` loop to iterate over the keys of the object...

```
for(var i=0; i<collections.length; i+=1) {
  for(var prop in collections[i]){
    if(collections[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      console.log("collection." + prop + "=" + collections[i][prop]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so i just tested your code and i get the following console log `collection.last=undefined` ....

Comment: this looks good, I was told to use a for in loop, for this kind of stuff..... thanks for clarifying for me!

Answer (score 1):

One can use `filter` method to filter out elements that satisfy the condition.  Also, since comparison of objects is needed in evaluating the condition, and there does not seem to be an `equals` method in JavaScript for Objects, one has to do additional work to check equality.

Here is one way the problem mentioned in question can be solved

```
function where(collection, source) {
  return collection.filter(function(item) { 
     return Object.keys(source).every(function(k){ return item[k] == source[k] });
  });
}

console.log (where([{ first: 'Romeo', last: 'Montague' }, { first: 'Mercutio', last: null }, { first: 'Tybalt', last: 'Capulet' }], { last: 'Capulet'}));
```

**Output**

```
[ { first: 'Tybalt', last: 'Capulet' } ]
```